# How do I fix a migration error I'm getting with South?

Tags: django, view, model, foreign-keys, django-south

I tried to change a field in the below model from CharField to ForeignKey and I get an error when I run the migration.  The error I get is:

FATAL ERROR - The following SQL query failed: CREATE INDEX "reserve_reviewbackup_fbfc09f1" ON "reserve_reviewbackup" ("user_id");
The error was: index reserve_reviewbackup_fbfc09f1 already exists
 ! Error found during real run of migration! Aborting.

! Since you have a database that does not support running
 ! schema-altering statements in transactions, we have had 
 ! to leave it in an interim state between migrations.

```
class Reviewbackup(models.Model):
    review = models.CharField('Review', max_length = 2000)
    user = models.CharField('Username', max_length =  200)
    rating = models.IntegerField(max_length=2, choices=RATING_OPTIONS)
    product = models.ForeignKey(Productbackup)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.review

user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='reviews')
```

Comment: Had this same error doing the same edition (changing a field type from CharField to ForeignKey without changing its name), sounds like a bug to me. (south 0.7.6)

Comment: To complete the described change with South, I used two steps :

1)First migration where I change both field's type and name (the name is set to a temporary value)

2)Second migration where I change field's name back to the original name (temporary name discarded).

Of course South already fudged up my Sqlite DB beyond repair... Let's take this as a great lesson to always dump all the DB content before migrating : `python manage.py dumpdata > savemyass.json`

Comment: Can you write the code before and after changes?

Answer (score 0):

I've done this before. Just manually delete the index from the database admin and everything works.